# XPath and XElement

Tags: vb.net

I have an `XElement` and an `XPath` expression that selects a node from it. It works fine in the original program that I wrote it in but doesnt work if I paste it to another program. I've checked the references and import statements. What am i doing wrong?

I think the problem might be that the original program had the code within the class of a wpf window while it was moved to a abstract class where it doesnt work.

Dim X As XElement = _

```
    Dim XPath As String

    XPath = "//Transform3DGroup/TranslateTransform3D"

    X.XPathSelectElement(XPath).SetAttributeValue("OffsetX", "5")

    Console.WriteLine(X.ToString)
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Not giving us enough information to help you. What do you mean by not working? Are you getting a runtime exception? Are you getting a compile-time failure? What is the nature of the error? Can you reproduce the problem in a short code snippet? Help us help you.

Comment: copy & paste, there's your problem

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

It seems as if the xpath isnt returning any values - doesnt find any matches.

But it does find matches in the other program.

Comment: I second the code snippet request

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. The original program had the code in the windows class. but i have moved the code to an abstract class. i still dont kn ow how to fix it though. would appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim X As XElement = _
```

```
    Dim XPath As String

    XPath = "//Transform3DGroup/TranslateTransform3D"

    X.XPathSelectElement(XPath).SetAttributeValue("OffsetX", "5")

    Console.WriteLine(X.ToString)
```